# Performance: Empty string or null in PHP

Tags: php, types, null, string

Since PHP treats them equally in string operations and output, I would like to know what is the best practice, to assign/concatenate a `null` value or an empty string:

```
$lang = 'lang';
$suffix = null;
$lang .= $suffix;
```

or

```
$desc = 'name';
$suffix = '';
$desc .= $suffix;
```

This can also be the case for inline conditions:

```
<div class="item<?= $is_selected ? ' selected' : null ?>"></div>
```

or

```
<div class="item<?= $is_selected ? ' selected' : '' ?>"></div>
```

I know it won't affect the overall performance, but could it compare to using double or single quotes?

Comment: This is not what you have asked about, but these values have different meanings. Use null for "no value" (value hasn't been assigned) and empty string for value which happened to be an empty string. PHP is a mess but it doesn't mean your code should be mess as well. You won't be able to optimise as much as well because you can't tell if your efforts won't be rendered useless by PHP interpreter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
> php --version
PHP 5.3.12 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: May  9 2012 11:44:31) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with Suhosin v0.9.33, Copyright (c) 2007-2012, by SektionEins GmbH
```

```php
php > $start = microtime(true); for( $i = 0; $i < 1000000; ++$i ) { $str = 'foo'; $str .= null; } printf('%.5f', microtime(true) - $start);
0.15258
php > $start = microtime(true); for( $i = 0; $i < 1000000; ++$i ) { $str = 'foo'; $str .= ''; } printf('%.5f', microtime(true) - $start);
0.11397
```

Ran this a few times, and got very similar results every time.

Conclusion:

- Appending an empty string to a string is **very slightly faster** than appending `null` to an empty string.
- Unless you are doing this inside a loop with **billions** of iterations, it doesn't matter from a performance standpoint, so use the one that makes better semantic sense.

Answer (score 2):

Null and empty string aren't exactly the same in PHP.

[Null (see PHP docs)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php) is basically "no value" and should be used when something hasn't been set yet. When something is `null`, `is_null($var)` will be true.

An empty string is still a string, just with length 0. You should use that when you know you have a string but it has no content.

So really it depends on your situation which one to use. When they are displayed as strings or echoed both will not print anything but internally they are still different. In my opinion though for this case I would use the empty string:

```
<div class="item<?= $is_selected ? ' selected' : '' ?>"></div>
```

Comment: Agreed. If you are outputting an empty string, you should use an empty string, if for no other reason, for readability.

Comment: This was not supposed to be a question of the theorical fitness of `null` for string operations. When you use inline conditions in php output tags, you're not really looking for beauty, if you know what I mean. But your answer is quite enlightening for those who may have a similar doubt.